Cross Compile grpc with cmake in aarch64
I'm using grpc v1.67.0.
host is Ubuntu 22.04
the host protoc and grpc_cpp_plugin compiled is ok.
cross-compile is aarch64-none-linux-gnu
gcc version 12.3.1 20230626 (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.3.Rel1 (Build arm-12.35))
the toolchain is below:
    SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
    SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
    set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /tmp/stage)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/lenli/he01/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.3.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/lenli/he01/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.3.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/tmp/toolchain.cmake \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/install \
      ../..
is ok.

After setting up for aarch64  and make "-j4" install throws some similar errors as below:
re2_arg_test.cc:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::ios_base()'

regexp_test.cc:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'

undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'

When the compilation progress reaches about 30%, many undefined errors occur as above
how can i finish cross-compile?
Or what may be causing the error?

[Edit] your question to include the error as text.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

The issue is linking to libstdc++.  It's either a problem with your toolcahin file or the actual cross-compiler toolchain.  Can you build a basic hello world C++ program with your cross-compiler?

thank your reply . i build a c++ template code by aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++. And it,s finished. In addition, the directory of the cross-compilation tool chain is /home/lenli/he01/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.3.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.
